# p:dataTable livescroll overrides js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

*JSF-2.0, Mojarra 2.1.19, PrimeFaces 3.4.1*

As it can be seen from my prev. questions I am using the `p:dataTable` to be able to show kind of status/comment module. And there is a JS/jQuery function which edits the CSS of dataTable rows;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var rowSize = '#{statusBean.size}';
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; rowSize; i++) {
        var rowIndex = i;
        var inputTextStr = 'dataTableForm' + ':dataTable:' + rowIndex + ':commentInput';
        var inputText = $(document.getElementById(inputTextStr));
        inputText.css({'box-shadow':'0 0 5px #EB2F28'});
    }
});
```

And `p:dataTable` is regular one with `liveScrolling=true` and assume it has one and only `p:inputText` which has the modified CSS by above function.

**Problem occurs** when the `p:dataTable` has lot's of rows. Assuming user scrolls down, `live scroll` event of the table is fired(ajax request) and the table loads more rows, but it loads `p:inputText` components with regular CSS. Function can not applies the css into recenlty loaded rows.

So there is need to catch that `liveScroll` event or warrant to JS function to work at each update of `p:dataTable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in AJAX event which can handle this situation so you must do it on your own. I will try to give you some suggestions.

First reorganize your JavaScript with creating function for this and call that function in loading page:

```
function applyMyCSS() {
    var rowSize = '#{statusBean.size}';
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; rowSize; i++) {
        var rowIndex = i;
        var inputTextStr = 'dataTableForm' + ':dataTable:' + rowIndex + ':commentInput';
        var inputText = $(document.getElementById(inputTextStr));
        inputText.css({'box-shadow':'0 0 5px #EB2F28'});
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    applyMyCSS();
});
```

Now, you should somehow handle this AJAX request in your backing bean. I investigated little bit and found out that when scrolling is occur specific parameter is sent whose name is `yourDataTableId_scrolling`, for example `myForm:myTable_scrolling`, and value of this parameter is `true`.

Add this somewhere in your page, best somewhere on top:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.onPageLoad('clientIdOfComponent')}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Be shore to put exact client id from page. You can use some utility PrimeFaces functions for this, for example `#{p:component('id')}` to get client id. This event will call your `onPageLoad()` function before view render and for every request (AJAX or non-AJAX). In that function you will filter your `liveScroll` event and handle it:

```
public void onPageLoad(String datatableId) {
  FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  if (RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().isAjaxRequest() && 
          "true".equals(fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(datatableId + "_scrolling")) {

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("applyMyCSS()");
  }
}
```

Note that this is not documented behavior and can be changed in future versions (but I don't expect this). I also created [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5295&q=livescroll&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary) for adding this functionality and maybe it will be added soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am going to track the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: I was testing this. It seems it's working good at first but when surf on other pages and return to this related page, if condition in the onPageLoad method always has the false condition therefore it never executes applyMyCSS() again after surfing on the other pages

Comment: Try to debug in `onPageLoad` method and see what are values of `datatableId` and parameters in parameter map. Maybe you just didn't assign right ID in method parameter.

Comment: I found out why but couldn't resolved. I have another dataTable in other page. And problem occurs when visiting this page and return to our dataTable

Comment: Well, that isn't request we are interested in, that will be handled by `jQuery(document).ready`, just debug requests generated on scrolling.

Comment: I resolved this dude nothing about your implementation, requests executions are all fine problem was; the other page has same function and it was manipulating the value of 'statusBean.sizeS' now they are using different fields and it's working like a charm!